# Why optional params passed while removed params fails in policy testing?

Tags: laravel

So, I have created a test for my app, the model is `Subscription` which is the `index` and `show` endpoint should be publicly accessible.

I created a Resource Controller to handle I/O from the client and a Policy to handle the authorization but here, I found something that seems kinda odd.

Inside the controller, I registered the policy on the constructor, like so:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api')->except(['index', 'show']);
    $this->authorizeResource(Subscription::class, 'subscription');
}
```

And then in the policy class, I modified the default generated methods like so:

```php
/**
 * Determine whether the user can view any models.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
public function viewAny(?User $user) // <-- notice here I make it optional, the original was required (without "?" mark).
{
    return true; // publicly visible
}
```

When I run the test, it passed.

```php
public function testSubscriptionIndexArePubliclyAccessible()
{
    $subscriptions = Subscription::factory(10)->create()->toArray();
    $response = $this->get(route('subscriptions.index'));
    $response->assertOk();
    $response->assertExactJson($subscriptions);
}
```

However, if I completely remove the `User $user` param from the method, the test would fail.

```php
public function viewAny() <-- if I do this, the test fail. Saying that "this action is unauthorized".
{
    return true; // publicly visible
}
```

So.. Why is this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are checks happening before a policy method or gate ability are called. One check is if the policy method can be called with a user, `canBeCalledWithUser`. This will check if there is an auth user and return `true`, if not it does other checks. The next check is if the method allows guest users, `methodAllowsGuests`, which will use reflection to get the parameter for that method and see if it has a type and is nullable, but there are no parameters so it returns `false`. So you end up with it not calling the method and treating it more like it doesn't exist, which is always `false` in terms of authorization checks.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L371 `@raw -> callAuthCallback -> resolveAuthCallback`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L530 `@resolveAuthCallback`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L390 `@canBeCalledWithUser`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L416 `@methodAllowsGuests`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L456 `@parameterAllowsGuests` - it does not make it to this method call

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's clear and straightforward. Anyways, do you have any reference for this? I would like to deep dive about how policy works in laravel but can't find anything on laravel's api documentation.

Comment: I can add some links to the methods in the source code if you would like, as you would want to see what is happening in the methods to see the flow ... what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Sure, I'll be happy with that.. I'm using laravel 8.x